# Pager at tablesorter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

i have this code
everything works fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

  // Initialize tablesorter
  // ***********************
  $("table")
    .tablesorter({
      theme: 'blue',
      widthFixed: true,
      sortLocaleCompare: true, // needed for accented characters in the data
      sortList: [ [0,1] ],
      widgets: ['zebra', 'filter']
    })

    // initialize the pager plugin
    // ****************************
    .tablesorterPager({

      // **********************************
      //  Description of ALL pager options
      // **********************************

      // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below
      container: $(".pager"),

      // use this format: "http:/mydatabase.com?page={page}&size={size}&{sortList:col}"
      // where {page} is replaced by the page number (or use {page+1} to get a one-based index),
      // {size} is replaced by the number of records to show,
      // {sortList:col} adds the sortList to the url into a "col" array, and {filterList:fcol} adds
      // the filterList to the url into an "fcol" array.
      // So a sortList = [[2,0],[3,0]] becomes "&col[2]=0&col[3]=0" in the url
      // and a filterList = [[2,Blue],[3,13]] becomes "&fcol[2]=Blue&fcol[3]=13" in the url
      ajaxUrl : 'ajaxServlet?page={page}&{filterList:filter}&{sortList:column}',

      // modify the url after all processing has been applied
      customAjaxUrl: function(table, url) {
          // manipulate the url string as you desire
          // url += '&cPage=' + window.location.pathname;
          // trigger my custom event
          $(table).trigger('changingUrl', url);
          // send the server the current page
          return url;
      },

      // add more ajax settings here
      // see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings
      ajaxObject: {
        dataType: 'json'
      },

      // process ajax so that the following information is returned:
      // [ total_rows (number), rows (array of arrays), headers (array; optional) ]
      // example:
      // [
      //   100,  // total rows
      //   [
      //     [ "row1cell1", "row1cell2", ... "row1cellN" ],
      //     [ "row2cell1", "row2cell2", ... "row2cellN" ],
      //     ...
      //     [ "rowNcell1", "rowNcell2", ... "rowNcellN" ]
      //   ],
      //   [ "header1", "header2", ... "headerN" ] // optional
      // ]
      // OR
      // return [ total_rows, $rows (jQuery object; optional), headers (array; optional) ]
      ajaxProcessing: function(data){
        if (data && data.hasOwnProperty('rows')) {
          var r, row, c, d = data.rows,
          // total number of rows (required)
          total = data.total_rows,
          // array of header names (optional)
          headers = data.headers,
          // all rows: array of arrays; each internal array has the table cell data for that row
          rows = [],
          // len should match pager set size (c.size)
          len = d.length;
          // this will depend on how the json is set up - see City0.json
          // rows
          for ( r=0; r < len; r++ ) {
            row = []; // new row array
            // cells
            for ( c in d[r] ) {
              if (typeof(c) === "string") {
                row.push(d[r][c]); // add each table cell data to row array
              }
            }
            rows.push(row); // add new row array to rows array
          }
          // in version 2.10, you can optionally return $(rows) a set of table rows within a jQuery object
          return [ total, rows, headers ];
        }
      },

      // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}'; possible variables: {page}, {totalPages}, {startRow}, {endRow} and {totalRows}
      output: '{startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})',

      // apply disabled classname to the pager arrows when the rows at either extreme is visible - default is true
      updateArrows: true,

      // starting page of the pager (zero based index)
      page: 0,

      // Number of visible rows - default is 10
      size: 25,

      // if true, the table will remain the same height no matter how many records are displayed. The space is made up by an empty
      // table row set to a height to compensate; default is false
      fixedHeight: false,

      // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables.
      // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; needed if you plan to add/remove rows with the pager enabled.
      removeRows: false,

      // css class names of pager arrows
      cssNext        : '.next',  // next page arrow
      cssPrev        : '.prev',  // previous page arrow
      cssFirst       : '.first', // go to first page arrow
      cssLast        : '.last',  // go to last page arrow
      cssPageDisplay : '.pagedisplay', // location of where the "output" is displayed
      cssPageSize    : '.pagesize', // page size selector - select dropdown that sets the "size" option
      cssErrorRow    : 'tablesorter-errorRow', // error information row

      // class added to arrows when at the extremes (i.e. prev/first arrows are "disabled" when on the first page)
      cssDisabled    : 'disabled' // Note there is no period "." in front of this class name

    });
});
```

html:

```
<body>
<div class="content">
<table class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
  <td class="pager" colspan="5">
    <img src="tablesorter-master/addons/pager/icons/first.png" class="first"/>
    <img src="tablesorter-master/addons/pager/icons/prev.png" class="prev"/>
    <span class="pagedisplay"></span> <!-- this can be any element, including an input -->
    <img src="tablesorter-master/addons/pager/icons/next.png" class="next"/>
    <img src="tablesorter-master/addons/pager/icons/last.png" class="last"/>
    <select class="pagesize">
        <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
    </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>1</th>
  <th>2</th>
  <th>3</th>
  <th>4</th>      
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tfoot>
 <tr>
  <th>1</th>
  <th>2</th>
  <th>3</th>
  <th>4</th>      
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="pager" colspan="5">
    <img src="tablesorter-master/addons/pager/icons/first.png" class="first"/>
    <img src="tablesorter-master/addons/pager/icons/prev.png" class="prev"/>
    <span class="pagedisplay"></span> <!-- this can be any element, including an input -->
    <img src="tablesorter-master/addons/pager/icons/next.png" class="next"/>
    <img src="tablesorter-master/addons/pager/icons/last.png" class="last"/>
    <select class="pagesize">
        <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
 <tbody> <!-- tbody will be loaded via JSON -->
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

All records are showing in the table!
The problem that i have is, that all of my records are shown on just one site(in this example 200 records), so the pager and the filtering not working.
What can i do, to solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Can you open the console (press F12 in the browser) and see if there are any javascript errors. Also, are you using pager ajax? or does the table contain all the rows?

Comment: Hi @Mottie i use pager ajax. There are no error codes in the firebug console of Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm since the code above doesn't show that jQuery and tablesorter were loaded - unless you loaded them separately, you'll need to load them using the `script` tag.